# Excel: Click cell to open the data to another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's my draft data

Sheet_name: ***"FIRST"***

The data represents the Pass and fail of ***X*** & ***Y*** fields. If the Area fails when it comes to ***X*** it will be mark as ***F*** and if it pass, the field ***X*** will mark as ***P***. Same procedure to Field ***Y***

[image]

And

Sheet_name: ***"SECOND"***

Here's the summary of the Sheet: *"FIRST"*
It calculates the counts of passes and fails. 
Using the idea of Countif Function.

=COUNTIF(FIRST!B2:B5,"P")

=COUNTIF(FIRST!C2:C5,"F")

[image]

What I'm trying to do is,

When you try to click the counts of passes and fails. It will redirect you to new sheet where the sheet gives the data who are the areas passed and failed.

Example:
If I click the "3" under the field of Passed
It will give me something like this,

```
       | X |
 Area1 | p |
 Area2 | p |
 Area4 | p |
```

Sorry, this one is not my project, homework, or exam.
I just need to understand the logic of opening the data when you click a cell.

Comment: Why is area 2 considered a pass but area 3 is not? And you want to create a brand new worksheet when you click that cell? What is to happen to the worksheet when you're finished with it? What are you going to name it? You'll need VBA for this - specifically a `Worksheet_Change()` event.

Comment: Also what if passed = 0?

Comment: If one of the parameters fails the result will be failed. Hmm this cant be done by using a formula?

Comment: *"If one of the parameters fails the result will be failed"* - then why is area 2 listed in the table but not area 3? They both have 1 failed parameter, no? And no, an excel formula cannot change the value of other cells (and it can't tell what you have selected on a worksheet).

Comment: The sheets should only contains the passes and fails of the area.

Comment: Sorry sir, the illustration confused us. I already updated my post.

Comment: Maybe you've already considered this and I'm missing something, but why don't you just use a pivot table? You'll be able to click and have the underlying data displayed on a new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

## Cell-Click to Another Sheet

- Copy the code into the Sheets("SECOND") sheet code (in VBA
  double-click on "SECOND") and rename a sheet as "THIRD".
- In sheet THIRD there will be 2 columns with headers AREA and X. The
  headers are excluded from ClearContents.
- Below the results will be either for Pass or Fail depending on which
  cell was 'clicked' (selected) at the moment.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const cStrPass As String = "A3"   ' Pass Cell Range
    Const cStrFail As String = "B3"   ' Fail Cell Range

    If Target = Range(cStrPass) Then
        CellClick Range("A3")
    End If

    If Target = Range(cStrFail) Then
        CellClick Range("B3")
    End If

End Sub

Sub CellClick(CellRange As Range)

    Const cVntName1 As Variant = "FIRST"
    Const cVntName3 As Variant = "THIRD"

    Dim vntSrc As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntTgt As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim lngLastRow As Long  ' Source Last Row
    Dim i As Long           ' Source Row Counter
    Dim k As Long           ' Target Row Counter
    Dim j As Integer        ' Source/Target Column Counter
    Dim strPF As String     ' PassFail String

    ' Paste Source Range into Source Array.
    With Worksheets(cVntName1)
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        vntSrc = .Range("A2", .Cells(lngLastRow, "B"))
    End With
    ' Determine PassFail String.
    If CellRange.Column = 1 Then
        strPF = "P"
      Else
        strPF = "F"
    End If
    ' Count rows for Target Array
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
        If vntSrc(i, 2) = strPF Then
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
    ' Write data to Target Array
    ReDim vntTgt(1 To k, 1 To 2)
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntSrc)
        If vntSrc(i, 2) = strPF Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(vntSrc, 2)
                vntTgt(k, j) = vntSrc(i, j)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    ' Paste Target Array into Target Range.
    With Worksheets(cVntName3)
        .Range("A2", "B" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(vntTgt), UBound(vntTgt, 2)) = vntTgt
        .Select
    End With

End Sub
```